# Compact Hausdorff implies product of quotient map is a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be compact Hausdorff and let $q : X \to Y$ be a quotient map. Is it true that $f : X \times X \to Y \times Y$ with $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (q(x_1), q(x_2))$ is a quotient map?